# PyCrypto not fully installed on Windows XP

Tags: python, windows, pycrypto

I ran `python setup.py install` in a Windows XP console, and it reported as follows:

```
running install
running build
running build_py
running build_ext
warning: GMP library not found; Not building Crypto.PublicKey._fastmath.
building 'Crypto.Random.OSRNG.winrandom' extension
error: None
```

When I try to run a script with `import Crypto.Cipher.AES`, it doesn't work, saying:

```
ImportError: cannot import name AES
```

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 43, accepted):

On windows, it may just be easier installing PyCrypto via a prebuilt windows installer. The Voidspace site has [PyCrypto 2.1 and 2.3 installers for Python 2.2-2.7](http://www.voidspace.org.uk/python/modules.shtml#pycrypto).

Comment: Voidspace's PyCrypto 2.6 release includes 32-bit and 64-bit builds for each supported Python version.

Answer (score 3):

For other people like me on 64 bit windows 7:

Short version:
Follow [this](http://yorickdowne.wordpress.com/2010/12/22/compiling-pycrypto-on-win7-64/) instructions.

Long version:

Install VC++ 2008 SP1 Express. you can get it from [here](http://www.microsoft.com/visualstudio/en-us/products/2008-editions/express#2008-Visual-CPP).

You also need the Windows SDK, specifically the [Win7 + Net 3.5 SDK](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=3138).

Maybe the [issue](http://bugs.python.org/issue7511) was already solved in your python version, if not get the diff file from the issue page

download [patch.py](https://code.google.com/p/python-patch/) (or any other tool to patch diff files)

if you downloaded the patch.py and diff file in `c:\Python27` just run:

```
python patch-11.01.py vcvars3.diff
```

Finally install using pip:

```
pip install pycrypto
```

Answer (score 0):

You may use [PyPM](http://docs.activestate.com/activepython/2.7/pypm.html) to install (pre-built binary package of) pycrypto:

```
C:> pypm install pycrypto
Ready to perform these actions:
The following packages will be installed:
 pycrypto-2.0.1
Get: [pypm.activestate.com] pycrypto 2.0.1-1
Installing pycrypto-2.0.1
```

To list the files installed, type:

> ```
> C:> pypm files pycrypto
> C:\Users\sridharr\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python26
> C:\Users\sridharr\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python26\site-packages
> C:\Users\sridharr\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python26\site-packages\Crypto
> C:\Users\sridharr\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python26\site-packages\Crypto\Cipher
> C:\Users\sridharr\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python26\site-packages\Crypto\Cipher\AES.pyd
> C:\Users\sridharr\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python26\site-packages\Crypto\Cipher\ARC2.pyd
> C:\Users\sridharr\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python26\site-packages\Crypto\Cipher\ARC4.pyd
> C:\Users\sridharr\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python26\site-packages\Crypto\Cipher\Blowfish.pyd
> C:\Users\sridharr\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python26\site-packages\Crypto\Cipher\CAST.pyd
> C:\Users\sridharr\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python26\site-packages\Crypto\Cipher\DES.pyd
> C:\Users\sridharr\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python26\site-packages\Crypto\Cipher\DES3.pyd
> C:\Users\sridharr\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python26\site-packages\Crypto\Cipher\IDEA.pyd
> C:\Users\sridharr\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python26\site-packages\Crypto\Cipher\RC5.pyd
> C:\Users\sridharr\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python26\site-packages\Crypto\Cipher\XOR.pyd
> C:\Users\sridharr\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python26\site-packages\Crypto\Cipher\__init__.py
> C:\Users\sridharr\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python26\site-packages\Crypto\Hash
> C:\Users\sridharr\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python26\site-packages\Crypto\Hash\HMAC.py
> C:\Users\sridharr\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python26\site-packages\Crypto\Hash\MD2.pyd
> C:\Users\sridharr\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python26\site-packages\Crypto\Hash\MD4.pyd
> C:\Users\sridharr\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python26\site-packages\Crypto\Hash\MD5.py
> C:\Users\sridharr\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python26\site-packages\Crypto\Hash\RIPEMD.pyd
> C:\Users\sridharr\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python26\site-packages\Crypto\Hash\SHA.py
> C:\Users\sridharr\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python26\site-packages\Crypto\Hash\SHA256.pyd
> C:\Users\sridharr\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python26\site-packages\Crypto\Hash\__init__.py
> C:\Users\sridharr\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python26\site-packages\Crypto\Protocol
> C:\Users\sridharr\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python26\site-packages\Crypto\Protocol\AllOrNothing.py
> C:\Users\sridharr\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python26\site-packages\Crypto\Protocol\Chaffing.py
> C:\Users\sridharr\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python26\site-packages\Crypto\Protocol\__init__.py
> C:\Users\sridharr\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python26\site-packages\Crypto\PublicKey
> C:\Users\sridharr\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python26\site-packages\Crypto\PublicKey\DSA.py
> C:\Users\sridharr\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python26\site-packages\Crypto\PublicKey\ElGamal.py
> C:\Users\sridharr\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python26\site-packages\Crypto\PublicKey\RSA.py
> C:\Users\sridharr\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python26\site-packages\Crypto\PublicKey\__init__.py
> C:\Users\sridharr\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python26\site-packages\Crypto\PublicKey\pubkey.py
> C:\Users\sridharr\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python26\site-packages\Crypto\PublicKey\qNEW.py
> C:\Users\sridharr\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python26\site-packages\Crypto\Util
> C:\Users\sridharr\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python26\site-packages\Crypto\Util\RFC1751.py
> C:\Users\sridharr\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python26\site-packages\Crypto\Util\__init__.py
> C:\Users\sridharr\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python26\site-packages\Crypto\Util\number.py
> C:\Users\sridharr\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python26\site-packages\Crypto\Util\randpool.py
> C:\Users\sridharr\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python26\site-packages\Crypto\Util\test.py
> C:\Users\sridharr\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python26\site-packages\Crypto\__init__.py
> C:\Users\sridharr\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python26\site-packages\Crypto\test.py
> C:\Users\sridharr\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python26\site-packages\pycrypto-2.0.1-py2.6.egg-info
> ```

PyPM can be installed by installing [ActivePython](http://www.activestate.com/activepython/).

Comment: _error: Can't install pycrypto-2.5: requires Business Edition subscription_

Comment: @DavidFreitas - try ActivePython 32-bit, not 64-bit.