# Problems installing Python Fabric on Windows 7

Tags: python, windows-7, fabric, easy-install

I'm trying to install Python Fabric on Windows 7 using the guide from [Getting Python and Fabric Installed on Windows](http://www.jonnyreeves.co.uk/2011/08/getting-python-and-fabric-installed-on-windows/).

What i did so far:

- Installed [Python 2.7](http://www.python.org/download/releases/2.7.2/) to C:\Python27
- Added the Python-Directory and Python/Scripts to the Windows System Paths
- Installed [SetupTools](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/setuptools#files)
- Installed [MinGW](http://sourceforge.net/projects/mingw/files/)
- Added MinGW-Directory to the System Path
- [Modified the distutils.cfg](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2817869/error-unable-to-find-vcvarsall-bat/2838827#2838827) to match the MinGW-Path

This seemed to work fine until now. When I try to install Fabric via `easy_install Fabric` it starts to download the files, but then i get an `chmod error`.

```
Using c:\python27\lib\site-packages\fabric-1.3.4-py2.7.egg  
Processing dependencies for fabric  
Searching for pycrypto>=2.1,!=2.4  
Reading http://pypi.python.org/simple/pycrypto/  
Reading http://pycrypto.sourceforge.net  
Reading http://www.amk.ca/python/code/crypto  
Reading http://www.pycrypto.org/  
Best match: pycrypto 2.5  
Downloading http://ftp.dlitz.net/pub/dlitz/crypto/pycrypto/pycrypto-2.5.tar.gz  
Processing pycrypto-2.5.tar.gz  
Running pycrypto-2.5\setup.py -q bdist_egg --dist-dir   c:\users\birgit\appdata\local\temp\easy_install-nzrlow\pycrypto-2.5\egg-dist-tmp-_pwkm4  
The command "chmod" is spelled wrong or could not be found.

Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "C:\Python27\Scripts\easy_install-script.py", line 8, in <module> load_entry_point('setuptools==0.6c12dev-r88846', 'console_scripts', 'easy_install')()  
 File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\setuptools-0.6c12dev_r88846-py2.7.egg\setuptools\command\easy_install.py", line 1712, in main  

 ... lots and lots of lines... (if they are relevant, I'll post them)

 File "C:\Python27\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 972, in run_command cmd_obj.run()  
 File "setup.py", line 269, in run  
RuntimeError: chmod error
```

Any suggestions to solve the problem?

Comment: have you tried a binary installer from Unofficial Windows Binaries for Python Extension Packages: [Base distribution may contain Fabric](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/).

Comment: The unofficial Windows Binaries helped solving the described Problem! Thank you!

Comment: I got the same Problem with PyCrypto and solved it again by using a [binary installer](http://www.voidspace.org.uk/python/modules.shtml#pycrypto) as suggested in [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1687283/why-cant-i-just-install-the-pycrypto) - and now finally I'm able to run Python Fabric scripts!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I have just managed to install fabric on win7 box, using information from various places in the net. That was really annoying, so just to save others frustration I put together the following list.

1. Install pip http://www.pip-installer.org/en/latest/index.html (that's easy, follow the guide on the web site, goes without problems)
2. run from command line `pip install fabric` - you'll get errors, some stuff about missing bat files, etc. while installing pycrypto.
3. Download precompiled pycrypto package from http://www.voidspace.org.uk/downloads/ *for your version of Python*, for instance for 2.7 it is http://www.voidspace.org.uk/downloads/pycrypto-2.1.0.win32-py2.7.zip
4. run again from command line `pip install fabric` - this time everything seems to be ok, until you try to run fabric script. It will complain about "No module named win32api", etc.
5. Install that missing win32api from http://sourceforge.net/projects/pywin32/files/pywin32/ - first choose a build version (newest, probably) and then again .exe file for your Python version.

And you are done, fabric should work ok.

Comment: The pycrypto install didn't detect my python install - but still said it succeeded - be careful there.

Comment: Pycrypto also failed to install properly.  Had to move some files manually from c:\PythonX\ to c:\Python27\.  Had gotten the error "No module named OSRNG"  Found the answer here:   http://devblog.alexsapps.com/2012/10/solution-to-importerror-no-module-named.html

Answer (score 2):

have you tried a binary installer from Unofficial Windows Binaries for Python Extension Packages: [Base distribution may contain Fabric](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/).

Answer (score 1):

If you're using virtualenv, you need to add one point to Piotr Kochanski's answer: when creating the virtualenv, allow it to access the system packages so it can see pycrypto. By default it disallows this.

These steps worked for me:

1. Install pycrpyto binary from http://www.voidspace.org.uk/python/modules.shtml#pycrypto.
2. Create a virtual env that can access the system packages. For example:

   `c:\Python27\Scripts\virtualenv.exe --system-site-packages c:\Proj\virtualenv`
3. `pip install fabric`

Comment: Now that I think about it, I wonder if I could have installed pycrypto into the virtualenv and not needed to allow access to the system packages. Maybe I'll try that next time.

Comment: Yes, you could have using `easy_install` from within the virtual environment: `easy_install .\pycrypto-2.6.win32-py2.7.exe`.

Answer (score 0):

1.Create a virtualenv (I usually put all mine on the desktop)

2.Download the binary of pycrypto (matching your installed python version and architecture -- no support for python3 as of now) - http://www.voidspace.org.uk/python/modules.shtml

3.Navigate to the easy_install executable (under Lib\site-packages) within the virtualenv folder you created and run the pycrypto install - 'easy_install C:\path\to\the\download\pycrypto-2.6.win-amd64-py2.7.exe'

4.Activate the virtualenv and 'pip install fabric'