# Python easy_install throws chmod-error

Tags: python, windows, chmod, easy-install

I'm trying to install Python Fabric on Windows 7 using the guide from [Getting Python and Fabric Installed on Windows](http://www.jonnyreeves.co.uk/2011/08/getting-python-and-fabric-installed-on-windows/).

To install PyCrypto and Fabric, i used easy_install, as recommended in the guide, but both failed, returning an chmod-error:

```
Using c:\python27\lib\site-packages\fabric-1.3.4-py2.7.egg  
Processing dependencies for fabric  
Searching for pycrypto>=2.1,!=2.4  
Reading http://pypi.python.org/simple/pycrypto/  
Reading http://pycrypto.sourceforge.net  
Reading http://www.amk.ca/python/code/crypto  
Reading http://www.pycrypto.org/  
Best match: pycrypto 2.5  
Downloading http://ftp.dlitz.net/pub/dlitz/crypto/pycrypto/pycrypto-2.5.tar.gz  
Processing pycrypto-2.5.tar.gz  
Running pycrypto-2.5\setup.py -q bdist_egg --dist-dir   c:\users\birgit\appdata\local\temp\easy_install-nzrlow\pycrypto-2.5\egg-dist-tmp-_pwkm4  
The command "chmod" is spelled wrong or could not be found.

Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "C:\Python27\Scripts\easy_install-script.py", line 8, in <module> load_entry_point('setuptools==0.6c12dev-r88846', 'console_scripts', 'easy_install')()  
 File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\setuptools-0.6c12dev_r88846-py2.7.egg\setuptools\command\easy_install.py", line 1712, in main  

 [... lots and lots of lines... (if they are relevant, I'll post them)]

 File "C:\Python27\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 972, in run_command cmd_obj.run()  
 File "setup.py", line 269, in run  
RuntimeError: chmod error
```

I don't know much about this chmod-thing, but I thought there is no chmod in Windows?

How can i get easy_install to actually work?

I postet a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9131323/problems-installing-python-fabric-on-windows-7), where (thanks to @J.F. Sebastian) I found a workaround to install those packages without fabric. But now I do want to know, how to actually solve the problem I'm having with easy_install.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Log in as the administrator of your machine. `chmod` refers to permissions for accessing directories, and in this case, I have a feeling python is complaining about Windows 7's UAC (user account control). Creating directories in `C:\` requires elevated permissions in Windows.

Comment: Thank you! The UAC did the job!

Comment: Also, for other who are having this issue, you can press `Shift + Enter` to run a program as an administrator, instead of signing into a different account. You'll still need the password, though.

Answer (score 8):

[Download](http://sourceforge.net/projects/mingw/) and install `MinGW - Minimalist GNU for Windows`.

To making some Unix commands accessible from the windows console, set in your `env` variables:

```
C:\MinGW\bin;C:\MinGW\mingw32\bin;C:\MinGW\msys\1.0\bin;C:\MinGW\msys\1.0\sbin
```

.

Alternatively, from the console:

```
PATH=%PATH%;C:\MinGW\bin;C:\MinGW\mingw32\bin;C:\MinGW\msys\1.0\bin;C:\MinGW\msys\1.0\sbin
```

Answer (score 0):

If there's something obvious happening at line 269, you could just edit the script to take out the offending line.

If not, you could install all of the dependencies, and manually install Fabric.

Also, consider using virtualenv and pip.

Comment: I think I would like to keep the files as they are... especially because I don't know python very well.

Answer (score 0):

I can see that you are on a Python 2.x. Thus, I will suggest the method that worked for me.

Download the Pycrypto installer from : [Here](http://www.voidspace.org.uk/downloads/pycrypto26/pycrypto-2.6.win32-py2.7.exe).

Then do the usual steps. Select the Lib/Site-packages in which you want to install it, I had two Python installations (Python 2 and 3, thus I selected Python 2/Lib/Site-packages).

Go till the end.

After successful installation, open the IDLE and type:

```
from Crypto.Hash import SHA256
```

If it works without any error, you are good to go.

Cheers.

Note : I am on a windows 8 machine.